# In VS Code can I change the width of the split editor panel with a shortcut or command?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code When I have a vertical editor split with 2 panels I would like to be able to change the right panel's width to a predefined total window width % using a shortcut.

Say I would like to have one shortcut to show the right panel at 50% of the overall VSC width. Then the second shortcut is 30%, the third is 80% and the 4th is 0%.

At the same time I would not like to have any files from the right editor panel joined or closed when I change the panel's width.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a sketchy workaround that binds keyboard shortcuts to decrease view height/width a bunch of times and then increases it a couple times and adjust the number of times doing each until it works for your screen size:

```json
{
    // for width
    "key": "", // TODO
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            "workbench.action.decreaseViewWidth",
            "workbench.action.decreaseViewWidth",
            "workbench.action.decreaseViewWidth",
            "workbench.action.decreaseViewWidth",
            "workbench.action.decreaseViewWidth",
            "workbench.action.decreaseViewWidth",
            "workbench.action.decreaseViewWidth",
            "workbench.action.decreaseViewWidth",
            "workbench.action.decreaseViewWidth",
            "workbench.action.decreaseViewWidth",
            "workbench.action.increaseViewWidth",
            "workbench.action.increaseViewWidth",
            "workbench.action.increaseViewWidth",
            "workbench.action.increaseViewWidth",
            "workbench.action.increaseViewWidth",
        ],
    },
},
{
    // for height
    "key": "", // TODO
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            "workbench.action.decreaseViewHeight",
            "workbench.action.decreaseViewHeight",
            "workbench.action.decreaseViewHeight",
            "workbench.action.decreaseViewHeight",
            "workbench.action.decreaseViewHeight",
            "workbench.action.decreaseViewHeight",
            "workbench.action.decreaseViewHeight",
            "workbench.action.decreaseViewHeight",
            "workbench.action.decreaseViewHeight",
            "workbench.action.decreaseViewHeight",
            "workbench.action.increaseViewHeight",
            "workbench.action.increaseViewHeight",
            "workbench.action.increaseViewHeight",
            "workbench.action.increaseViewHeight",
            "workbench.action.increaseViewHeight",
        ],
    },
},
```

You could merge those into a single keybinding for both height and width.

And no, I can't think of a better solution right now.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the VS Code behavior that partially resembles the feature I described above.

To see this we have to split the editor in 2 panels (`View->Editor Layout->Two Columns`), open some file in the right hand one, manually move its border to the farthest right. Then as we switch between the panels with `Ctrl-1` and `Ctrl-2` (Windows) the respective active panel will restore its maximum width and the other will get the minimum width.

This does not fully solve my problem but at least alleviates the pain.